# click a button from a java-script function

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I am trying to get a java-script function to click a hidden button in order to execute some code.  I wrote a short program to try and test this method.

Here I establish two buttons.

```
 <div><button>test</button></div>
    <div class="rowHidden"><button id="testHiddenButton">open the dialog</button></div>
```

Below is my java-script.

```
function clickTestButton() {
    $("#testHiddenButton").trigger("click");
       }

    $("#test").click(function () {
        clickTestButton();
       });

    $(#"testHiddenButton").click(function () {
         alert("TESTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT");
       });
```

The idea is that when the first button is clicked, it triggers the next button to click.  This does not work though.  It seems like the page processes something but the alert never goes off.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you loading jQuery properly? Are you executing the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two errors

Error 1: You have to declare an id for the first button

```
<div><button id="test">test</button></div>
<div class="rowHidden"><button id="testHiddenButton">open the dialog</button></div>
```

Error 2: The # needs to be inside the selector string.

```
$("#testHiddenButton").click(function () {
    alert("TESTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT");
});
```

Comment: Just noticed the ID before I saw your post.  And I fixed error 2.  It works now.  Now I have make it apply to my main program.  Thanks for the help.